# Let $G$ a group and $A,B$ two normal sub group of $G$. Prove/disprove $A\leq B\implies G/B\leq G/A$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ a group and $A,B$ two normal sub group of $G$ such that $A\leq B$. Do we have $$G/B\leq G/A\ \ ?$$
Or at least $G/B\subset G/A$ (as set) ? To be honest, the righting $G/B\leq G/A$ look a little bit strange to me, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: No, neither holds, as can be checked by some small examples. It is correct that inequality holds between the sizes, but not inclusion of the sets, except when they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can say there exists a surjective group homomorphism
$$
G/A \to G/B
$$
defined by $xA\mapsto xB$.

This map is well defined, because, if $xA=yA$, then $xy^{-1}\in A$, so $xy^{-1}\in B$ and therefore $xB=yB$. That it is a surjective homomorphism is obvious.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's stated in the question